# Is it possible to compare value in list when user input in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I am working in kotlin. I want to know is there any way when we entering value we know which value is smallest in the list.

For example

```
var userInputList = mutableList<Boolean>()
```

**User Input Number** -> 5

```
userInputList -> false
```

**Again User Input Number** -> 2

```
userInputList -> false, true
```

**Again User Input Number** -> 7

```
userInputList -> false, true, false
```

**Again User Input Number** -> 1

```
userInputList -> false, false, false, true.
```

Main thing I want to know, which one is smallest number.

Comment: Of course there is.  What have you tried?  In general, you would not construct this on the fly.  You would input the whole list, then compute the maximum value and find its index.

Comment: @TimRoberts I know about how can we compare whole list. I was wondering can we do at a time when we entering the value. My question is about for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val list = mutableListOf<Int>()

while (true) {
  val i = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: break
  list.add(i)
  val bools = list.fold(emptyList<Boolean>()) { acc, value ->
    acc + (value == list.minOrNull()!!)
  }
  println(list)
  println(bools)
}
```

This is an attempt to show the steps of *fold:*

```
Input:  5 2 7 1 3
Output: [false, false, false, true, false]

acc          value   to evaluate      evaluated       why is f ot t added?
[]           5       [] + f           [f]             5 is not the minimum value
[f]          2       [f] + f          [f,f]           2 is not the minimum value
[f,f]        7       [f,f] + f        [f,f,f]         7 is not the minimum value
[f,f,f]      1       [f,f,f] + t      [f,f,f,t]       1 is the minimum value
[f,f,f,t,f]  3       [f,f,f,t] + f    [f,f,f,t,f]     4 is not the minimum value
```

Comment: perfect answer. thanks a million

Comment: can you tell me. What is `fold`? and what this line do `acc + (value == list.minOrNull()!!)` ?

Comment: _fold_ iterates over a list (or other iterables). On each visited element you have access to two variables. The accumulator holds the result of all previously visited elements, and value is the current element. You then return a new accumulator, thereby combining the 'old' accumulator with the current element. The whole thing needs a start value, in this case an _emptyList_ of booleans, since we want to collect booleans. So the line _acc + (value == list.minOrNull()!!)_ takes the list of booleans and adds _true_ or _false_ depending on the comparison of _value_ with the minimum value in _list_

Comment: Note that in a lambda, there is no return statement; the result of the last expression is returned implicitly (which is the result of the evaluation of _acc + (value == list.minOrNull()!!)_).

Comment: I added a section showing the steps of the _lambda_ of the _fold_.

Comment: great explanation thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `minOrNull` function

```kotlin
val elements = mutableListOf<Int>()

fun main() {
    
    while(true) {
        print("Enter a number:")
        elements.add(
            readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: break
        )
        val smallestElement = elements.minOrNull()
        println("The smallest element in the list now is $smallestElement")
    }
    println("Bye bye!")
}
```